# Why is the results of groupby with mean aggregate is different between sample(frac=1) and original data?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I don't know if this really a basic question..

So I have been playing with Groupby, aggregating, and sampling using Pandas.. with this sample.csv file
https://sendeyo.com/en/a36d65b2a7

Here is a results of original data groupby using mean aggregate ('i' here is a DataFrame):

```
    test1 = i.groupby('State')[["Precipitation","Speed"]].mean() 
    test1.head(5)

                  Precipitation     Speed
     State                              
    Alabama          0.925000       5.891875
    Alaska           0.488824       8.630924
    Arizona          0.234000       4.015500
    Arkansas         0.380833       4.372500
    California       1.017763       4.192895
```

And then here is a results of data using sample(frac=1, replace=True) groupby using mean aggregate:

```
    i_sampling = i[["Precipitation","Speed","State"]].sample(frac=1,replace=True)
    test2 = i_sampling.groupby('State')[["Precipitation","Speed"]].mean()
    test2.head(5)

                   Precipitation     Speed
    State                              
    Alabama          0.810588       5.951765
    Alaska           0.416984       9.862222
    Arizona          0.082500       3.581875
    Arkansas         0.494118       3.469412
    California       1.103448       3.536207
```

**But I fail to understand and accept these results, Here is my Understanding:**

My concept of understanding, sample(frac=1,replace=True) is making a DataFrame having a 100% sample of DataFrame with randomize index (replace=True), and I was thinking this is just like a randomized Index DataFrame, So I was expecting that the groupby mean of original and sampling must be same.

**And my Question is:**

**But the results is shown difference? Can someone explain me why can this happen?**.. I am aware that a lot of research using these methods for Bootstrap Analysis, (so this question is only to clarify how the aggregate and groupby works for this case)

(Note: Of Course I accept if it is a different cases, example: using frac below 1, that means sample just use a proportion of DF (below 100%), so its clear if the results come difference)

Comment: not sure if this is the case here, but typically you need to _sort_ your data before performing groupby.

Comment: remove `replace=True` and they will become same.

Comment: @Chris, okay so it fixed when replace=False :o, Thank You!

Comment: So, I wonders how replace=True does work?

Comment: Without replace, it is doing pure shuffle. With replace, you can’t guarantee that resulting data has identical distribution

Comment: so in other words, replace=True, makes sample data become a bit different from the original?

Comment: You pick one sample, keep it but replace back to the pool. In theory, you may end up all same rows. Thats the definition of replacement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankyou @Chris for feedback!, this minimalistic plot shows that

> replace=True

does give effects the sample distribution even a little bit, this is makes sense as a method of Bootstrap:

```
i_sampling_true = i[["Precipitation","Speed","State"]].sample(frac=1,replace=True)
i_sampling_false = i[["Precipitation","Speed","State"]].sample(frac=1,replace=False)

def dataframe_distplot(df, col, rug=True, hist=False, title_df="Title DF", color="Red", axes="None"):
     if axes == "None": sns.distplot(df[col], color=color, rug=rug, hist=hist).set_title(title_df)
     else: sns.distplot(df[col], ax=axes, color=color, rug=rug, hist=hist).set_title(title_df)

ax = dataframe_distplot(i, "Precipitation", True, False, title_df="Dist Plot Original vs Replace=False")
dataframe_distplot(i_sampling_false, "Precipitation", True, False, title_df="Dist Plot Original vs Replace=False",color="blue", axes=ax)
```

[image: Original vs No Replace]

```
ax = dataframe_distplot(i, "Precipitation", True, False, title_df="Dist Plot Original vs Replace=True")
dataframe_distplot(i_sampling_true, "Precipitation", True, False, title_df="Dist Plot Original vs Replace=True",color="yellow", axes=ax)
```

[image: Original vs With Replace]